# Is it possible to have Perl run shell script aliases?

Tags: perl, bash, ssh, ssh-keys

Is it possible to have a Perl script run shell aliases? I am running into a situation where we've got a Perl module I don't have access to modify and one of the things it does is logs into multiple servers via SSH to run some commands remotely. Sadly some of the systems (which I also don't have access to modify) have a buggy SSH server that will disconnect as soon as my system tries to send an SSH public key. I have the SSH agent running because I need it to connect to some other servers.

My initial solution was to set up an alias to set ssh to ssh -o PubkeyAuthentication=no, but Perl runs the ssh binary it finds in the PATH instead of trying to use the alias.

It looks like the only solutions are disable the SSH agent while I am connecting to the problem servers or override the Perl module that does the actual connection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alter the PATH before you run the perl script, or use this in your .ssh/config

```
Host *
  PubkeyAuthentication no
```

Comment: I would think this would be the preferred way if you had specific hosts that were problematic.  Then instead of * you could put the host (or a mask matching your problem hosts).  Documentation for ~/.ssh/config is in ssh_config(5).

Comment: After messing with things, I think the .ssh/config option will work out better. I'm connnecting to all the problem hosts via IP address (been told that DNS isn't reliable in this case - a completely different issue). But the systems that work, I am connecting using the hostname. So  Host 10.* PubkeyAuthentication no should resolve the issue quite nicely.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps you could put a command called `ssh` in `PATH` ahead of the `ssh` which runs `ssh` as you want it to be run.

Comment: Great idea! Why didn't I think of that before? Anyway, apparently great minds think alike - I got two identical answers at the same time.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you skip the alias and just create a shell script called `ssh` in a directory somewhere, then change the path to put that directory before the one containing the real `ssh`?

I had to do this recently with `iostat` because the new version output a different format that a third-party product couldn't handle (it scanned the output to generate a report).

I just created an `iostat` shell script which called the real `iostat` (with hardcoded path, but you *could* be more sophisticated), passing the output through an `awk` script to massage it into the original format. Then, I changed the path for the third-party program and it started working fine.

Answer (score 0):

You could declare a function in .bashrc (or .profile or whatever) with that name. It could look like this (might break):

```
function ssh {
  /usr/bin/ssh -o PubkeyAuthentication=no "$@"
}
```

But using a config file might be the best solution in your case.